Using Lagrange Multiplier with an inequality Calc 3
Using Lagrange Multiplier when testing for ABS extrema on inequalities.
The Stewart textbook doesn’t have much. And following Paul’s Notes, if I read it correctly, the steps are:

Check the inequality region for critical points.
Then use Lagrange Multiplier to check for critical points (as an equality).

Why does it have to be tested separately and therefore what is the limitation of Lagrange multiplier (from a calculus 3 level).
$$
\text { Find the maximum and minimum values of } f(x, y)=4 x^2+10 y^2 \text { on the disk } x^2+y^2 \leq 4 \text {. }
$$

There is a generalization of Lagrange multipliers to inequality constraints, known as the Karush-Kuhn-Tucker (KKT) conditions https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions#Necessary_conditions. However, the necessary conditions for stationarity are much more involved. To avoid doing this, we just check separately in an intro calculus class.

Think about in calculus 1, if you want to find the maximum on an interval, you need to check at critical points inside the interval, and then you need to check the endpoints of the interval. The same is true here.  You need to check critical points inside your region, but then you also have to check on the boundary. Lagrange multipliers is how you check the boundary.

Lagrange multipliers can only be used to find local maxima and minima for functions $f$ subject to some equality constraint $g(x,y)=c$ (where $f$ and $g$ need to be $\mathcal{C}^1$).
So in this case Lagrange multipliers may be used to find the extreme values for $f$ at the circle $x^2+y^2=4$; you can check there are two local maxima: $(0,-2)$ and $(0,2)$, where $f$ attains the value $40$, and two minima: $(-2,0)$ and $(2,0)$, where $f$ attains the value $16$.
We also need to look for extreme values at the interior of the disk, that is, the region $x^2+y^2<4$. But this is an open set, and thus at maxima and minima the partial derivatives must vanish. This means there is only one extreme value at this region, a minimum at $(0,0)$, where the function takes on the value $0$.

The region $x^2+y^2 \leq 4$ defines a compact set and your objective function is continuous, a fortiori, maximisers and minimisers will exist. They will either fall in the open disc $< 4$ or the frontier $= 4$; the necessary conditions are that the derivative is zero on the open set and the derivative is a linear form evaluated on the derivative of the restriction on the frontier. Namely, if $f$ is your objetive function and $g \leq 4$ your constraint, then, if the optimiser lies in $g < 4$ then you must have $f' = 0,$ and if the optimiser lies in $g = 4,$ one must have $f' = \lambda \circ g'$ for some $\lambda:\mathbf{R} \to \mathbf{R}$ linear (i.e., just multiplication by some scalar), therefore, one can write then $\nabla f(x,y) = \lambda \nabla g(x,y)$ for some $\lambda \in \mathbf{R}.$

The inequality can be transformed into an equality by doing
$$
x^2+y^2\le 4\equiv x^2+y^2+s^2 = 4, \ \ s \in \mathbb{R}
$$
so the augmented lagrangian reads:
$$
L(x,y,s,\lambda) = 4x^2+10y^2+\lambda(x^2+y^2+s^2 - 4)
$$
and now we can proceed as usual.

We can use the linear programming approach here with this question. Put $u = x^2, v = y^2$ then we optimize $f(u,v) = 4u+10v$ subject to $0 \le u \le 4, 0 \le v \le 4, u+v \le 4$. The conditions on $u,v$ creates a triangular region in the first quadrant whose vertices are $A(0,0), B(0,4), C(4,0)$. The extreme values of the function occurs at these vertices. The min is clearly $0$ at $(u,v)= (0,0)$ and the max is $40$ which occurs at $(u,v) = (0,4)$.
